# Beginner resources for genealogical DNA tests

Tags: dna, research-guides

When I go to the internet to learn about how to understand DNA testing, I find two types of websites (1) sites that are so simple as to be worthless to any relatively educated person, or (2) sites like this one that are written for people who already way more than I do and I can't understand what they are talking about.

Does anyone have a recommendation for a URL where people of average intellect can learn to understand the basics?

Comment: I think this question could be much improved by clarifying what level of information is being asked for, and by asking the question in language which is more neutral.  The question could have shown research effort: 'These sites (list 1) didn't have enough information and I don't understand these sites (list 2) so I need something in between.'  The current wording of the question is very unfriendly to DNA beginners who may need a simple site to start with.  Someone can be "a relatively educated person" and still be a *beginner* at learning about DNA.

Answer (score 5):

I don’t know a single website addressing most relevant topics for beginners. The following book however is suitable for this purpose:

- Blaine T. Bettinger: *T[he Family Tree Guide to DNA Testing and Genetic Genealogy](http://www.shopfamilytree.com/guide-to-dna-testing-and-genetic-genealogy)* (Family Tree Books, October 13, 2016), ISBN 1440345325

( I am not affiliated with the author or publisher.)

Answer (score 3):

I always recommend the Wiki at the ISOGG (International Society of Genetic Genealogy) site for any and all information on genetic genealogy.

For beginning material, they have an entire page of [Beginners' guides to genetic genealogy](https://isogg.org/wiki/Beginners%27_guides_to_genetic_genealogy) with links to Articles, Resources, Company articles, Paths of DNA inheritance, Guidelines and standards, Mailing lists and Facebook groups, Videos and webinar, E-books, and ISOGG Wiki articles for beginners.

But if I had to recommend just one introductory guide that's really good (and this one is somehow left out of ISOGG's beginning links), I'd suggest Stephen Morse's "[From DNA to Genetic Genealogy - Everything you wanted to know but were afraid to ask](http://stevemorse.org/genetealogy/dna.htm)"

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a quick easy guide to commercial tests, I wrote a blog post about this which can be found here: http://familytreetips.co.uk/2016/08/13/an-easy-guide-to-commercial-genealogical-dna-tests/

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend you two great blogs regarding the question

- https://dna-explained.com/
- https://gcbias.org/

They can be difficult to read though but both resources are very useful and shed light on some important but non-obvious matters.